# Sorting row by row

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a table in excel which has values like below

```
2   1   3
6   5   4
7   2   3
```

Considering the rows do not have a column header, what is the easiest way to sort them row by row, such that I get the below output

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
2   3   7
```

Comment: On real data, i checked and there is a max of 27 columns. It is not square .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array starts in A1 please try (UNTESTED) in AB1 copied across 27 columns and down to suit:

```
=SMALL($A1:$AA1,COLUMN()-27)
```

Comment: I just checked with a small sample of real data. It does sort but lexicographically instead of numerical. I may need this as well , but how would it change if i wanted numerical sorting.

Comment: I still don't get them sorted as numbers. But guess i can figure that out. The main issue was to get them sorted row by row and this formula helps. Thanks!